# PHP MySQL: Get data from one column but by using id from different columns in separate table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So here's the problem I'm having. I have two separate tables TableA and TableB, TableA has four columns and TableB has two. TableA holds only ids while TableB holds id and string. So I need strings from TableB but based on the ids from TableA

For example:

TableA:

```
+------+------+-------+------+
| m_id | appi | mainy | desy |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 6    | 9     | 13   |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 2    | 7    | 10    | 14   |
+------+------+-------+------+
| 3    | 8    | 12    | 15   |
+------+------+-------+------+
```

TableB

```
+------+-------+
| t_id | str   |
+------+-------+
| 6    | dude  |
+------+-------+
| 10   | bro   |
+------+-------+
| 9    | lol   |
+------+-------+
| 14   | homie |
+------+-------+
```

Based on the tables above I need to find out the actual strings based on the ids from TableB, something like `SELECT str FROM TableB WHERE t_id = (Ids from TableA WHERE m_id=1)`. So my expected data should be 'dude' and 'lol' because `m_id=1` has two ids 6 and 9, and those ids in TableB have strings 'dude' and 'lol'. I would really appreciate any help and sorry if there's any confusion, please let me know and I'll try to address that.

Comment: This database design is pretty broken, frankly. You should start by normalizing your data so that you don't have one table (TableB) with data that corresponds unpredictably to 3 different columns in another table (TableA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `JOIN` of TableB to TableA, where `t_id` from TableB must be one of the values of `appi`, `mainy` or `desy` from TableA for a given `m_id`:

```
SELECT b.str
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA a ON b.t_id IN (a.appi, a.mainy, a.desy)
WHERE a.m_id = 1
```

Output:

```
str
dude
lol
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81d4c6e9fb79fa3ebab66056807b3796)

Comment: On large tables this would become slower than the "exists" function.

Comment: @cornel.raiu on large tables the `EXISTS` function will become very slow because the `WHERE` condition has to be computed for every row in the table.

Comment: you are right. Just did a quick benchmark on this case. It turns out that, when using subqueries, Join is much faster than EXISTS. +1 for you :)

Comment: Dude Nick! You're awesome! this totally worked fine for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` for the this type of logic:

```
select b.str
from tableb b
where exists (select 1
              from tablea a
              where a.m_id = 1 and
                    b.t_id in (a.appi, a.mainy, a.desy)
             );
```